# WP - loops does not work anymore when I try to add custom post type in category and tag taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories, custom-post-type

I would like to add my custom post type to default category and tag taxonomy.

I've found this code that do the job. But on those pages I now dont have menu and other loops anymore.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

        $post_types = array( 'post', 'test', 'jeu', 'elysium', 'hardware', 'jeux-inde'/*, 'concours' */);

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Any Idea Why is that so ?

Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if( is_category() || is_tag() && $query->is_main_query()  ) {

        $post_types = array( 'post', 'test', 'jeu', 'elysium', 'hardware', 'jeux-inde'/*, 'concours' */);

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
    return $query;
}
```